# How is most performant way to scale and set precision of decimal

Tags: c#, decimal, scale, precision

I have a class that I set scale and precision:

```
public class MyDecimalConverter
{
    public int Scale { get; }
    public int Precision { get; }

    public MyDecimalConverter(int scale, int precision)
    {
        Scale = scale;
        Precision = precision;
    }

    public decimal ConvertDecimal(decimal decimalValue)
    {
        return  //Calculated value
    }
}
```

Also, it has the `ConvertDecimal` method. I want to calculate provided decimal value based on scale and precision. For example, when

- Precision = 5
- Scale = 4
- Provided decimal value = `123456789`,
- The method should return `1,2345`

Here is a screenshot about what is scale and what is precision:

[image: scale]

I didn't find this kind of function in Math class. So I want to know a proper and performant way of making this kind of function

Comment: You've specified `scale = 4` so why is the output not `12345.6789`? What would the output be for `precision=5; scale=0;`?

Comment: @haldo It cannot be 12345.6789 because precision is 5, the decimal output cannot have length more than precision. In case precision = 5 and scale =0 it will be 12345

Comment: If you're doing this specifically to meet the constraints of a database, and if that database is SQL Server in particular (which the terms "precision" and "scale" lead me to think), have a look at the `SqlDecimal` structure, which has `AdjustScale` for exactly such occasions.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found that you can set both precision and scale is this:

```
public static decimal SetPrecisionAndScale(this decimal number, int precision, int scale)
{
    System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal x;
    x = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal(number);
    var convertedNumber = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(x, precision, scale);
    return convertedNumber.Value;
}
```

I am not sure about performance tough, but I use this code in production and it works fine (without hiccups, memory leaks or performance bottlenecks).